# Get an element's value without an id

Tags: javascript, html

I've got following HTML:

```
<span class="testClass1" >
  <a href="testlink.com">wanted Text</a>
  <a class="ctx" href="#"></a>
</span>
```

Now I want to get the text `"wanted Text"`.
How can I achieve this?

I tried with:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("testClass1");
```

I also tried with `document.getElementsByTagName()` but I don't know how to use them properly.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` creates an array.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".textClass1 > a:first-child").textContent`

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName will not work with IE 8. Use document.querySelectorAll instead.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('span.testClass1 a')[0].innerHTML` - i.e you want the innerHTML of the a element, which exists as a child of a span with the specified class. Since `querySelectorAll` returns an array, we also say that we want the first element in that array.

Comment: thank you squint, it works fine.

Comment: @user3052891: Just keep in mind that very old browsers don't support `querySelector[All]`, and IE8 doesn't support some selectors, like `:first-child`, so the proper solution depends on what you're supporting. The `:first-child` could actually be dropped to make it IE8 compatible, assuming you only have one of these to target.

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectorAll

hence:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.testclass1 a')
```

will return all the  `<a>` items children of a `.testclass1`

Snippet example:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.testClass1 a')

console.log(elements) // open the console to see this
console.log(elements[0].text) // this gets the first <a> text `wanted Text`
```

```html
<span class="testClass1" >
  <a href="testlink.com">wanted Text</a>
  <a class="ctx" href="#"></a>
</span>
```

Comment: downvoter may explain what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: You don't have any downvotes, but you're not targeting the specific `a` element with the desired content.

Comment: I had one.. than again an upvote, then again a downvote.. then again a upvote... 

I'm editing the answer to cover the specific `a` element thought

Answer (score 1):

The [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function returns an array of matching elements, so if you need to access them, you could do so using a loop :

```
// Get each of the elements that have the class "testClass1"
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass1");
// Iterate through each element that was found
for(var e = 0; e < elements.length; e++){
     // Get the inner content via the innerHTML property
     var content = elements[e].innerHTML;
}
```

If you need to actually access the `<a>` tags directly below some of the elements as your edit indicates, then you could potentially search for those wihtin each of your existing elements using the [`getElementsbyTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) function :

```
// Get each of the elements that have the class "testClass1"
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass1");
// Iterate through each element that was found
for(var e = 0; e < elements.length; e++){
     // Find the <a> elements below this element
     var aElements = elements[e].getElementsByTagName('a');
     // Iterate through them
     for(var a = 0; a < aElements.length; a++){
        // Access your element content through aElements[a].innerHTML here
     }
}
```

You can also use an approach like [squint's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint) comment or [Fred's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36755321/557445) which take advantage of the `querySelectorAll()` function as the `getElementsByClassName()` and `getElementsByTagName()` are better served when accessing multiple elements instead of one specifically.

Comment: Best answer for the given question.

Comment: And who downvoted the answer? if you downvote at least give a reason why?

Comment: seems like someone had fun downvoting?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: I did because it's very obviously wrong. Now why did you upvote it?

Comment: Because it explains to the user what `getElementsByClassName` is doing and how to use it. It might not be the correct method for the problem however it does explain why.  "I guess you can use the following methods, but I do not know how to use them properly" <-- does the above answer not show OP how to use `getElementsByClassName()` properly?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Sure, still didn't answer the question. Even after the update, it's a pretty marginal solution.

Comment: @Rion: There was no edit that changed the intent of the question. It was always the text in the first `<a>` that was targeted.

Comment: @squint, I realized that after the bevy of comments that flooded this answer. You should consider posting your commented solution as that's clearly the way to go. I'll gladly upvote it. I misunderstood OPs original intent (namely that they didn't know how to properly use `getElementsByClassName()` for this kind of purpose).

Comment: Seems to me that @squint is just doing the normal round of trolling with not much productive effort.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: The answer was wrong. You asked for a reason for the vote, so I gave one and now you're calling me a troll. Unbelievable.

Comment: @squint thank you for updating why you downvoted (but with 29k rep) you should know that it is outta respect to other to explain why you downvote, you asked why I upvoted, so I explained why. If you want to argue about my upvote, I would say you are just looking for an argument... Because at the end of the day, this answer is not on the top... does not really change anything if the answer is at 0 or -1 so why is this conversation even continuing... Trolling for a disagreement maybe?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: You ended your explanation with a question, and so I answered it. The conversation continues because you keep responding, and asking questions and hurling accusation. I'm merely offering you the courtesy of a reply. You claim that I'm not doing anything productive, and yet I gave a correct answer below the question and corrected the wrong answers. I'm pleased with the contribution I've made here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("testClass1")[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText
```

Comment: `.childNodes[0]` won't work because the first node will be a textNode in most browsers

Answer (score -1):

```
var testClass1 = document.getElementsByClassName("testClass1");
console.log(testClass1[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, but now i get 
"<a href="testlink.com">wanted Text</a><a class="ctx" href="#"></a></span>"

I only want the name of the link ("wanted Text")